# Azure Synapse: Show where Integration Pipeline is called

Tags: integration, pipeline, azure-synapse

I have a huge `Azure Synapse` project with visual integration pipelines. How can I see in which other pipelines a selected pipeline is called/triggered - how can I find the callers?

Comment: In synapse pipeline, Select the pipeline. Click **properties** in that pipeline. And then select **Related**. Pipelines which depends on the selected pipeline will be listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Synapse: Show where Integration Pipeline is called

- In synapse pipeline, Select the pipeline.
- Click **properties** in that pipeline.
- And then select **Related**.
- Pipelines which depends on the selected pipeline will be listed.

[image]